# How do I show specific items in my Roles SelectList depending on the logged in status?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am populating the following `SelectList` in my Account Controller:

```
ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(_context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
```

The select list currently displays all the roles I create and displays them on my registration form. Now, I wish to limit it to only one option if the user is logged out, (ie. display only the `Registered Users` role). How do I accomplish this?

Comment: if (IsNotLoggedIn) ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(_context.Roles.First(x=>x.Name == "Registered Users")....)

Comment: @Steve I tried several variations of this code and I get IEnumerable errors

Comment: Why bother to show it at all? You forcing them to use the single role, just don't offer them a choice.

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this should work

```
if(IsNotLoggedIn)
{
    ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(_context.Roles.Where(x => x.Name == "Registered Users").ToList(), "Name", "Name");
}
```